# Laravel : Undefined variable in a POST function

Tags: php, variables, laravel, undefined

I'm trying to send a post request containing a variable, but it says that the variable is undefined, here is my code ..
The first function is the view containing the form.
The second function is the callback of the post request of the form.
I echo'ed out the variable in the view and it succeeded but the error shows up in the second function ..

```
public function reset($code)
{
    return View::make('recover', array('code' => $code, 'passwordReset' => 1,'noLoginForm' => 1));
}

public function postResetPassword()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array('temppassword' => 'required','newpassword' => 'required|min:6','cnewpassword' =>'required|same:newpassword'));

    if($validator->fails())
        return View::make('recover', array('passwordReset' => 1,'noLoginForm' => 1))->withErrors($validator);
    else {
// The error shows up in the following line in the code variable comparison
        $user = User::where('temp_password','!=','')->where('code','=',$code)->first();
        if($user) {
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('newpassword'));
            $user->temp_password = '';
            if($user->save())
                return Redirect::route('login')->with('msg','Password changed correctly, use your new password to login.');
        } else {
            return View::make('recover', array('passwordReset' => 1,'noLoginForm' => 1,'error' =>'Invalid temporary password, please make sure you typed the password sent to you correctly.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error log

```
[2014-11-13 09:50:15] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: code' in C:\wamp\www\buddyly\app\controllers\UserController.php:155
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\app\controllers\UserController.php(155): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(8, 'Undefined varia...', 'C:\wamp\www\bud...', 155, Array)
#1 [internal function]: UserController->postResetPassword()
#2 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\bootstrap\compiled.php(5776): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('postResetPasswo...', Array)
#4 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\bootstrap\compiled.php(5764): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(UserController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'postResetPasswo...')
#5 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\bootstrap\compiled.php(4971): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'UserController', 'postResetPasswo...')
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#7 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\bootstrap\compiled.php(5329): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#8 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\bootstrap\compiled.php(4996): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\bootstrap\compiled.php(4984): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\bootstrap\compiled.php(715): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\bootstrap\compiled.php(696): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\bootstrap\compiled.php(7744): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#13 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\bootstrap\compiled.php(8351): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#14 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\bootstrap\compiled.php(8298): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#15 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\bootstrap\compiled.php(10957): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#16 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\bootstrap\compiled.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\public\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#18 C:\wamp\www\buddyly\server.php(19): require_once('C:\wamp\www\bud...')
#19 {main} [] []
```

Comment: your `$code` is called but not set yet in your method, or you if `$code` is from an input it will need `Input::get('code')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$code` isn't defined in that function or handed to it by a parameter, it doesn't exist. Hence the 'undefined variable' error you are getting.

If you send `$code` to the view, and want get `$code` back when the view posts a form, then add the value of `$code` to a form-element and read it with `Input::get()`.

View:

```
  <!-- inside your form -->
  <input type="hidden" name="code" value="{{ $code }}" />
```

Model/Controller:

```
$code = Input::get('code');
```

Alternatively, you could create a session containing `$code` and read the value once the method `postResetPassword()` is called.